# float left on a responsive video div and a paragraph

Tags: html, css

Here is what i have so far:

[image]

I have a responsive video and a paragraph.
What i would like to happen is to have this kind of result:

1. The text will appear on the right if the size is wide enough.
2. Text will appear on the bottom if the size is too small.

Here is my fiddle code:
https://jsfiddle.net/sLzxs5su/6/

```
.viddiv{
   float:left; width:50%;  
}

.vidholder{
    position:relative;height:0;padding-bottom:50%;
}

iframe{
    position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%;top:0;left:0;

}
```

adding float left on the paragraph will make my video disappear for some reason.

Comment: What defines "wide enough" and "too small"?

Comment: oops sorry, i mean the browser. I want it to be responsive.

Comment: You need to specify a pixel value of the viewport width at which you want the text to go alongside the video.

Comment: are there any other methods? i am not yet that familiar with viewports. I was thinking of a CSS solution that will allow my text to appear on the right.

Comment: You need to specify breakpoints to be able to make a layout responsive

Comment: "viewport" just means the width of the window or area you are viewing the html in. http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html#link9

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS3 Media Queries to solve this
The detail for [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp)
And a good tutorial for [Responsive Web design](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/your-first-multi-screen-site/?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this CSS:

```
.flag {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.flag__image,
.flag__body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.flag--top .flag__image, .flag--top
.flag__body {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.flag--bottom .flag__image, .flag--bottom
.flag__body {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.flag__image {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.flag__image > * {
  display: block;
  max-width: none;
}
.flag--rev .flag__image {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.flag__body {
  width: 100%;
}
```

With this HTML:

```
<div class="flag">
  <div class="flag__image">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hqiNL4Hn04A" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="flag__body">
    <p> @@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@ @@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@ @@@@@@@</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Requirement:

1. The text will appear on the right if the size is wide enough.
2. Text will appear on the bottom if the size is too small.

**Logic:** (for requirement 1)

1) use figure element & contain video inside it (html5).

2) use figcaption element after video and declare your text accompanied by `<p>` tag inside it then declare figure element to occupy 100% width since it is the conainer for video and text both. After that, declare video element width to be 50% (or suit your self). since you want it to left side of text, hence declare it as `float:left`

3) declare figcaption to take up rest of the width i.e. (since you want it to the right of video for big screens, hence you would have to use `float:right`

**Logic:** (for requirement 2)

1) to go for small screens, you need to use media queries and hit minimum width after which layout should change... i.e. `max-width: 400px`.

2) since you want to bring text to the bottom, you are, technically, asking the text div to take up new row and hence declare this its width to 100%

code:

```
figure {
    width:100%;
}
figure iframe{
    height:100%; width:50%;float:left;

}

figure figcaption {
    width:50%;
    float:right;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

figure iframe{
    height:100%; width:100%;

}

figure figcaption {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
}

<div class="vidholder">
<figure>
    <iframe width="480" height="390" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hqiNL4Hn04A" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <figcaption>
        <p style=" word-wrap: break-word;"> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLzxs5su/8/)

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/Lgb4de7u/

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="video-container">
        <iframe width="480" height="390" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hqiNL4Hn04A" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <p>@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@</p>
</div>
```

And the CSS here:

```
.column {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}

.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
    .column {
        float:none;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but i want the text to go on the right if the browser screen is wide enough and be like the one you posted if it's narrow.

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta - The text does wrap to right of width if the screen is wide enough. I updated my answer to include the revisions that were made.

I'm also not sure why my post was voted down or deleted. Can anyone provide insight to this?